# Swapping rows in $I$ and transpose

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $I$ denote the $n \times n$ identity matrix. Let $E$ denote $I$ with two arbitrary columns swapped. It seems to be true that then $E^T = E$ in this case (not true if you swap more than $2$!)

Why does this hold? Could someone show me how to prove it? Maybe the proof would provide intuitive insight into why this should indeed be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\dots, n\}$ be given.

Starting from the identity matrix $I = [\delta_{i,j}]$, where $\delta_{i,j}$ is the Kronecker symbol, define a matrix $E_\sigma = [\delta_{i,\sigma(j)}]$. Thus the $j$th column of the new matrix is column number $\sigma(j)$ of the old one.

Now $E_\sigma^T = [\delta_{j,\sigma(i)}]_{i,j} = [\delta_{\sigma(i),j}] = [\delta_{i,\sigma^{-1}(j)}] = E_{\sigma^{-1}}$.

When $\sigma$ is simply a transposition, we have $\sigma^{-1} = \sigma$, which explains the phenomenon you referred to. This occurs if and only if $\sigma^2 = 1$.

Comment: That is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for! Just a minor thing: shouldn't it be 
$ E_\sigma^T = [\delta_{\sigma(j)i}]$ when $E_\sigma = [\delta_{i\sigma(j)}]$?

Comment: I see, thank you. And why is $[\delta_{\sigma(i)j}] = [\delta_{i\sigma^{-1}(j)}]$?

Answer (score 1):

When you swap, say, columns $k$ and $l$, preserving the rest, you have $a_{lk}=a_{kl}=1$ withe zeros on the remaining positions. But for $E^T$ this is the same equation.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitive insight . . .

Your matrix $E$ is $I$ with two columns swapped, so $E^T$ is $I^T$ with two rows swapped.  But the rows and columns of $I$ are the same, so . . .

With some care I think you could write this up as a formal proof.